# How to insert data from csv file to JMS in talend using talend open studio for big data

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have a .csv file that contain some data. I need to create a job that insert data from .csv file to jms in talend using talend open studio.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you add some more informations : what did you already try, what component did you use..we'll need more informations to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of column you need to create a metadata of a delimitedfile (right click on it in the lef menu) and after that you need to make a job like :

tFileInputDelimited --> tmap --> tJMSOutput.